# Alsamixer returns "cannot open mixer: No such file or directory"

Tags: sound, jack

alsamixer returns:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

after

```
sudo apt install jack


sudo lspci -v | grep -i audio returns
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01) 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd High Definition Audio Controller 04:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: VIA Technologies Inc. ICE1712 [Envy24] PCI Multi-Channel I/O Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: VIA Technologies Inc. M-Audio Delta Audiophile 2496
```

Thanks!

Comment: `/usr/bin/alsamixer` : `apt install alsa-utils`

Comment: Try following #4 on this blog post http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/

Comment: This is the age old bug. You can detect soundcards that are USB soundcards (sadly that's most souncards today including the PCI ones they are PCI with USB stuff glued on) and you can detect these ONLY if there is a non USB soundcard in the system already. If you don't have a non USB soundcard you can't open the mixer. If you blacklist the module for the non-usb soundcard then you can't open the mixer either. It is the most annoying thing.

Answer (score 27):

Had the same problem. Running alsamixer with the -c parameter worked for me:

```
alsamixer -c 1
```

`1` is the card number (because I have multiple cards attached). You can change the card number and test the command. It shouldn't break anything.