# Audio card not recognised

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, intel

I realize this is a pretty common question but I did not find a solution for my problem on the other posts.
Just recently the audio on my pc, a Dell Precision Tower 3620 running Ubuntu 16.04, has completely stopped working, I do not recall modifying any settings or doing updates to packages related to the audio, but there is no sound anymore.
I can not open alsamixer because I get the following output:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

I also attach the output of a couple of other commands that I found quoted in other answers:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards

 1 [NVidia_1       ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17
 2 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf5080000 irq 17
```

These looks like the two NVIDIA cards that I have on my pc; in the past there were three entries while executing this cose, the third one being an "intel card" entry.

In fact, here it is another command with its output:

```
 lspci -v | grep -i audio

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
04:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
```

EDIT: I had a couple of ther outputs:

```
 cat /proc/asound/devices

  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 2]   : control
  3: [ 2- 3]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 2- 7]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 2- 0]: hardware dependent
  6: [ 1]   : control
  7: [ 1- 3]: digital audio playback
  8: [ 1- 7]: digital audio playback
  9: [ 1- 0]: hardware dependent
 33:        : timer
```

and

```
cat /proc/asound/modules
 1 snd_hda_intel
 2 snd_hda_intel
```

Edit:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -i audio -A2 is the following
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [1028:06b7]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fbc] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1098]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fbc] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1098]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Is there something wrong with my card?

Comment: Add the output of `lspci -knn | grep -i audio -A2`, post  as plain text.

Comment: Is the sound icon present on your system?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/922726/ubuntu-17-04-dummy-output/1019666#1019666

Comment: Is audio enabled in BIOS/EFI ?

Comment: @mattia.b89 yes, the audio in enabled in the BIOS

Comment: @JoKeR  have a sound icon dsplayed throug i3blocks and no, it does not show up

Comment: @saitam Trying it now.

Comment: @saitam tried that, no visible changes

Comment: 1) Have you seen this https://askubuntu.com/questions/800863/alsamixer-returns-cannot-open-mixer-no-such-file-or-directory ? 2) Are you in the `audio` group?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with ALSA. Try reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils libasound2 linux-image-`uname -r`
```

and reboot. I had the same problem a while ago and it worked.

Comment: I just tried that and did not help, I have the exact same behaviour as before

Comment: Have you modified the ALSA config files at any point?

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Comment: For good measure I also did: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils libasound2 linux-image-\`uname -r\``. But it didn't resolve my problem with "Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)"