# Pulseaudio no longer identifies bluetooth speaker; ubuntu 22.10

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, 22.10

I recently made the upgrade to ubuntu 22.10. Following this update I can no longer use bluetooth to connect audio devices as pulseaudio can no longer identify them.

I have tried solutions from the following threads but none of these have worked.

[bluetooth headset connects but not showing in sound settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481951/bluetooth-headset-connects-but-not-showing-in-sound-settings)

[Bluetooth speaker connected but not listed in sound output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824404/bluetooth-speaker-connected-but-not-listed-in-sound-output)

when loading module-bluetooth discover with sudo the following error is returned

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Without Sudo the error is

```
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

When I unload the module and reload it, I don't get these errors, but my bluetooth speaker still doesn't show up on pulseaudio.

Here is some more information that may be relevant.

Trying to load `alsamixer` returns the following

```
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:337:(snd_dlobj_cache_get0) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_ctl_pipewire.so (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pipewire.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
cannot open mixer: No such device or address
```

However, following this thread, I can open the mixer
[Alsamixer returns "cannot open mixer: No such file or directory"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800863/alsamixer-returns-cannot-open-mixer-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
pacmd list-sinks returns
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 43252 /  66% / -10.83 dB,   front-right: 43252 /  66% / -10.83 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 31.58 ms
    max request: 6 KiB
    max rewind: 6 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 15
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

in case you are wondering about any missing packages here is `dpkg -l | grep pulse`

```
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64              1.20.3-1ubuntu1                                amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio (transitional package)

ii  libcanberra-pulse:amd64                    0.30-10ubuntu1                                 amd64        PulseAudio backend for libcanberra

ii  libpulse-dev:amd64                         1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          amd64        PulseAudio client development headers and libraries

ii  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64              1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          amd64        PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)

ii  libpulse0:amd64                            1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          amd64        PulseAudio client libraries

ii  libpulse0:i386                             1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          i386         PulseAudio client libraries

ii  libpulsedsp:amd64                          1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          amd64        PulseAudio OSS pre-load library

ii  pipewire-pulse                             0.3.58-2ubuntu1                                amd64        PipeWire PulseAudio daemon

ii  pulseaudio                                 1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          amd64        PulseAudio sound server

ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server

ii  pulseaudio-utils                           1:16.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu3                          amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
```

Would appreciate any insight, tried reinstallng pulseaudio, but I am really cautious of further modifications as broken audio and bluetooth has been the sole cause of 5 reinstalls in less than 6 months. If I cant get it working consistently I am going to have to switch back to windows :(

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 22.1 so a good start is to have accurate info.

Comment: lsb_release -a returns
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.10
Release: 22.10
Codename: kinetic

Comment: Suggest you edit and correct the question and in your other question as well.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 uses PipeWire as default audio system - maybe look into this?

Comment: Hi, yeah, I had to swap over from Pipewire, I couldn't get it to work with anything, switched over to pulseaudio and it was working fine for a couple months until this update. Thanks for input (and for fixing my post)